# Name of a simple equivalence relation on real numbers?

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic, equivalence-relations

Define the relation $x \sim y$ where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers to hold if and only if there exist natural numbers $n$ and $m$ such that $x^n = y^m$.

It is easy to see that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. My question is if this equivalence relation naturally shows up in some setting and perhaps has been named (or perhaps the equivalence classes of it have been named)?

Comment: I assume that in this context $0$ is not a natural number?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that this relation shows up naturally, but one natural name for it is *the squares have commensurable logarithms* (in any and all bases).

Comment: clearly the equivalent class of $0$ consists only of $0$. Furthermore, $(x)^2 = (-x)^2$ so without loss of generality it suffices to consider $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: @WillieWong, right. I've fixed my answer...